# Install PHP 7 on Ubuntu 16

Tags: php, ubuntu

I tried to set PHP version to 7 in my Ubuntu 16, but the install ended with an error:

```
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running php -v the php version remains the same:

```
mycomputer@mycomputer:~$ php -v

PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

I follow these instructions from this link:

```
https://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-on-ubuntu/
```

Which are:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -yphp7.0
```

How can I fix the error and fix it to have PHP 7 installed on my Ubuntu 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line is telling you where to look at:

```
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Can you check whether you have some error on your `/etc/environment` file?

Comment: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games;ANDROID_HOME="/home/mycomputer/Android/Sdk/"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin"

Comment: this is my enviroment file

Comment: You are missing a quote: `/usr/local/games"`

Comment: I see it!, i fix and the php install now works, thank you